# Authentication info is not set when path variable is called with suffix .html

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Assume I have following controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/dashboard/{id}")
public void dashboard(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    User user = springSecurityUtils.getUser();  //some logic with authentication info
}
```

And following config:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false).setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }
}
```

When I call `/dashboard/abc` I get a non-null user related to current session. Within the very same session, when I get `/dashboard/abc.html` user is null, so is `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`. As a result my logic halts. Any solutions? Why does this url even mapped to this handler?

Comment: To what url pattern is your security filter mapped and what urls are you protecting...

Comment: @M.Deinum somehing like: `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/bla/**"/*some urls that does not include anything related to /dashboard */).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()`

Comment: Please be a bit more precise and add it to your question...